# Typed arrays not supported : LibGDX + GWT

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx, typed-arrays

I am using LibGDX to deploy a HTML5 game thanks to GWT. Currently I am having some issues with a random error that just appeared:

> uncaught exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: typed arrays not supported

It works on Chrome, Safari but not on Firefox. It was working a couple versions ago so I went back on GIT and recompiled and I still get this error.

It works on all three browsers while debugging in SuperDev mode but when it comes to compiled version in the server Firefox won't load due to this problem. Since it works on debug it might be some compile configuration that is out of my version control, but I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of issues that came up for me back in the early days of Java (Java 1.0, 1.1) where to get anything to work cross-platform / cross-browser, you really had to rely strictly on the common denominator (ie Java 1.0) eshew virtually all of the AWT toolkit and build everything yourself.

So... What I'm saying is that if it is necessary that this work on Firefox, I'd recommend you not use typed arrays, but rather use the least common denominator :-)

Comment: Yes, it is important to make it work in all browsers. I really don't know where I 'started' using typed arrays for this to break now.